# Save columns as csv pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to save specific columns to a csv using pandas. However, there is only one line on the output file. Is there anything wrong with my code? My desired output is to save all columns where d.count() == 1 to a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd

results = pd.read_csv('employee.csv', sep=';', delimiter=';', low_memory=False)
results['index'] = results.groupby('Name').cumcount()
d = results.pivot(index='index', columns='Name', values='Job')
for columns in d:
    if (d[columns]).count() > 1:
        (d[columns]).dropna(how='any').to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: Where's the part in your code that writes to a file? I'm not seeing anything like [`results.to_csv(filename)`] (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Comment: Thank you Tom. I forgot to copy it here.

Comment: How many columns in your dataframe? The placement of the output code within the column-loop might cause it to write out to a file multiple times, replacing the contents each time until the final column is interrogated.

Comment: I have 34 rows and 797 columns

Comment: Since you are writing the row to csv in the loop, its over-writing the csv is each iteration and gives you output with only the last row. Anyway there is almost always a non-loop solution in pandas. It would be easier if you provide d.head()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative might be to populate a new dataframe containing what you want to save, and then save that one time.

```
import pandas as pd

results = pd.read_csv('employee.csv', sep=';', delimiter=';', low_memory=False)
results['index'] = results.groupby('Name').cumcount()
d = results.pivot(index='index', columns='Name', values='Job')
keepcols=[]
for columns in d:
    if (d[columns]).count() > 1:
        keepcols.append(columns)
output_df = results[keepcols]
output_df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

No doubt you could rationalise the above, and reduce the memory footprint by saving the output directly without first creating an object to hold it, but it helps identify what's going on in the example.

Comment: It is raising this error: ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 34 to array axis with dimension 797

Comment: OK I'll do some tests.

Comment: I found a mistake and edited it, the line `keepcols.append(d)` should have read `keepcols.append(columns)` - the idea I'm guessing you want to achieve is to build a list of qualifying columns, and then only save that "stripe" of data. I've tested it and got it to work for a toy dataset.